# Do Self Types make the Calculus of Inductive Constructions obsolete?

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory, functional-programming, inductive-datatypes

Self Types are an extension of the Calculus of Constructions [1] that allow the language to express algebraic datatypes encoded through the Scott Encoding. The Scott Encoding provides one the ability to pattern-match in `O(1)`, which is one of the main motivators for the inclusion of inductive definitions on CC. Yet, Self Types are make for a much simpler and elegant base theory, and are seemingly no less powerful.

Do Self Types, under a theoretical point of view, make CIC obsolete, or is there still some aspect on which CIC is favorable in relation to Self Tyes?

[1] http://staff.computing.dundee.ac.uk/pengfu/document/talks/mvd-2012.pdf

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but why aren't self types just general recursive types (eg unsound?) This isn't a goal for all dependently typed things but it certainly is import to CiC to be sound. The linked presentation has type in type as well but I don't think that's related/necessary.

Comment: @jozefg Indeed: “Will be inconsistency as logic, but no problem for programs.” You should post this as an answer.

Comment: Isn't that comment addressed for `* : *`, @GIlles, not for `Self`?

Comment: @srvm with the typing rules they wrote, both are sources of unsoundness. Do you have a link to the paper?

Comment: @jozefg I suppose it's this one: http://staff.computing.dundee.ac.uk/pengfu/document/papers/rta-tlca.pdf

Comment: From the paper, "his allows deriving induction principles in a total type theory, and we believe it is the missing piece of the puzzle for dependent typing of pure lambda calculus.". It does look that they claim it is sa total type theory, so, logically sound. Am I wrong?

Comment: @srvm You're correct, they restrict self types to be strictly positive (not general recursive types) so it's sound modulo needing universes. My question is answered :)

Comment: Sooo my question is unanswered then?

Comment: I think no. Inductive types are more complex than self types (alone). Each new inductive type definition introduces multiple objects in addition to a type. It introduces a type plus a set of constructors and an inductive elimination. You can't lambda encode all of them in CoC only extended with self types because all them are mutually recursive. All of this is explained in more detail in the paper you link. You need to add mutual recursion, which breaks Curry-Howard correspondence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an expert in this work, but it seems to me that the major current issue is a lack of SN proof, even with restrictions. These proofs are notoriously tricky though, even when the calculus is correct, so I'd give it a little time. The work is certainly very promising.

One thing to note is that these restrictions are actually quite non-trivial to express, which is a large part of the complexity of the formulation of the inductive families in the CIC. The real selling point of an approach like this would be to concisely formulate these conditions.

It's been a somewhat longstanding open problem to have a dependently typed language which is

- Consistent/Normalizing
- Can express all the type families from Coq (or even Agda)
- Allows for a simple expression of recursion over these families
- Simple or has a small number of core constructions ($\Pi,\Sigma,\mu$).

One such attempt that I know of is the Altenkirch & al [$\Pi\Sigma$](http://www.andres-loeh.de/PiSigma/PiSigma.pdf) language, which similarly lacks a full meta-theoretical study (and also isn't consistent without further restrictions).